# Flask: Calling a class that takes a Resource

Tags: python, flask

I have an endpoint that looks like:
`api.add_resource(UserForm,'/app/user/form/<int:form_id>', endpoint='user_form')`

My UserForm looks like:

```
class UserForm(Resource):
    def get(self, form_id):
       # GET stuff here
       return user_form_dictionary
```

If I had a function called get_user_form(form_id) and I wanted to retrieve the return value from UserForm's get method based on the form_id parameter passed in. Is there a way in Flask that allows for some way to call UserForm's get method within the program?

```
def get_user_form(form_id):
    user_form_dictionary = # some way to call UserForm class
    # user_form_dictionary will store return dictionary from
    # user_form_dictionary, something like: {'a': 'blah', 'b': 'blah'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a way to directly access the get method of the UserForm class from within your app, the only thing that springs to mind is to call the url for that resource but I don't recommend doing that.

Are you using the flask-restful extension by some chance? if so the below is based on the suggested intermediate project structure from there site [here](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/0.3.2/intermediate-usage.html#project-structure)

In a common module (this contains functions that will be used throughout your application)

common\util.py

```
def get_user_form(form_id):
    # logic to return the form data
```

Then in your .py that contains the UserForm class, import the util.py file from the common module then do the below

```
class UserForm(Resource):
    def get(self, form_id):
       user_form_dictionary = get_user_form(form_id)

       # any additional logic. i try and keep it to a minimum as the function called
       # would contain it. also this way maintanence is easier

       return user_form_dictionary
```

Then somewhere else in your app after importing the common module you can reuse the same function(s).

```
def another_function(form_id):
    user_form_dictionary = get_user_form(form_id)
    # any additional logic. 
    # same rules as before

    return user_form_dictionary
```

Answer (score 0):

Fetch and display the data using Javascript's Fetch API.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).